# Windows Forms Control for visualizing job steps

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I am looking for a (free) **windows forms control** for **visualizing jobs step / phases**.
Background: In my programm  tasks with more job steps are processed. The user should see, what the actual step (of the current taks( is actually processed (at best animated)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this application is using threads to prevent the UI from locking up during these long tasks, I would recommend looking into using the built in ReportProgress method built into Background workers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx

As for a control, you can update just about anything through the method.  I would recommend a textbox or label though.

If this isn't an option, could you clarify your scenario a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this nice control is a good choice for you:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedPictureBoxLib.aspx?fid=304779&select=1622964&fr=1#xx0xx

(especially the AnimatedPicturesProgressBar control)